# Is there any console output similar with ROS_INFO without "\n"?

Tags: ros, ros-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found that when I use ROS_INFO to output console message,it always output a line.

Is there any ROS output method only output the message I specify?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11016/is-there-any-console-output-similar-with-ros_info-without-%22%5Cn%22?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-08-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nothing I know about. `ROS_INFO()` and other ROS logging services send messages to a central logging facility where they are collected from many nodes. Sending incomplete messages does not make much sense in that environment.

You can accumulate a message string in your own code, waiting until a complete line is constructed before logging it. For that, the standard C++ or Python string operations are sufficient.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3